# Access to MSSQL query join with same field name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I had to upsize an Access project to Microsoft SQL Server (2008). I solved several issues but I got stuck with a query which does **allow adding new records** in the Access version, but I can't add new records through this query when using a MS SQL
backend.

The query SQL code is :

```
SELECT t_Ku.*, t_An.*, t_Ad.*
FROM (t_Ku 
INNER JOIN t_An ON t_Ku.KUID = t_An.fk_KundeId) 
INNER JOIN t_Ad ON t_Ku.KUID = t_Ad.fk_KundeID;
```

By varying this query I found out that it has to do with the fields which are use for joining the tables (fk_KundeID). The problem seems to be that 
two tables (t_Ad and t_An) have the same field name which is used for joining (Fieldname: fk_KundeId).

Does anyone have an idea how this issue can be solved without having to change the field name in the joined tables.

Thanks.

Michael

Comment: ***Possibly*** (read untested/unverified) Spell out each field in the select and alias the duplicate named ones instead of using tablename.*

Answer (score 0):

change your select query to explicitly name the columns with alias

```
SELECT t_Ku.KUID as TKUKUID, t_An.KUID AS TANKUID, .............
```

list all other fields; never use .* in SELECT query